# enabling eslint-react-hooks turns off all eslint rules

Tags: eslint, eslint-config-airbnb, eslintrc

I am trying to get `react-hooks` rules for eslint, but it doesn't seem to be working with my setup (VSCode, CRA, airbnb, tslint, prettier).

Here's my .eslintrc.json before it breaks:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": ["plugin:react/recommended", "airbnb", "prettier"],
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 2020,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".jsx", ".tsx"] }]
  }
}
```

Here are my `devDependencies`:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.5.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.0.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^10.1.0",
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^13.13.4",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.34",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.30.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.30.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^3.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  },
```

Then I tried adding the following to `extends` in `.eslintrc`:

```
"extends": ["plugin:react/recommended", "plugin:react-hooks/recommended", "airbnb", "prettier"],
```

I also tried placing `"plugin:react-hooks/recommended"` in a difference place in the array. No matter what I do, it will break all other lint rules, including its own.

I also tried adding the following to `plugins` and `rules`:

```
"plugins": ["react", "react-hooks", "@typescript-eslint"],
"rules": {
  // ...
  "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
  "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn"
}
```

And of course, the test code for checking the lint rules:

```js
  const [a, b] = React.useState("Hey");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    React.useMemo(() => {}, []);
    if (a) b("Yeppp");
    if (props.what) console.log(props.what);
    exampleMethod();
  }, []);

  const exampleMethod = () => {};
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention I also tried to use `airbnb/hooks` in `extends` as well:

```
"extends": ["plugin:react/recommended", "airbnb", "airbnb/hooks", "prettier"],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution so I am answering my own question.

The [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) docs says if using Create React App, to make sure *NOT* to add the module directly in `package.json`.
Hence, the solution is to remove `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` from `devDependencies`.